# How to remove a given element from a list of tuples and update it in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

Given a list of tuples, suppose all first elements of the tuples in the list are unique, that is, there are no duplicates.

Ex. `xs = [("a",4), ("f",9), ("l",4)]` is valid but `ys = [("a",4), ("f",9), ("a",7)]` is not.

I would like to implement two functions. The first one takes the first element of a tuple, and removes that tuple from the list. Suppose a tuple with the given first element already exists in the list.

Ex. `remove "f" xs` returns `[("a",4), ("l",4)]`.

Another one takes the first and second elements of a tuple respectively. Again suppose a tuple with the given first element already exists in the list. If the given second element is different from the one in the original list, update it.

Ex. `update "l" 7 xs` returns `[("a",4), ("f",9), ("l",7)]`.

How should I do this?

Comment: hint: `filter` and `(++)` and `elem`

Answer (score 1):

Don't consider this an answer, but a long comment. Not all code is written because this looks like a classroom exercise and you should solve it yourself.

First, consider using `Data.Map` since it provides this kind of functionality. If you need to implement it with lists you should go like below:

```
remove key []         = -- what list should return if the given one is empty?
remove key ((k,v):xs)
  | key == k  = -- what should I return If input key and comparing key are equal
  | otherwise = -- and if they are not? use recursion

update key value []         = -- what list should return if the given one is empty?
update key value ((k,v):xs)
  | key == k  = -- what should I return If input key and comparing key are equal
  | otherwise = -- and if they are not? use recursion
```